# Find all substrings that don't contain the entire set of characters

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

This was asked to me in an interview.

I'm given a string whose characters come from the set {a,b,c} only. Find all substrings that dont contain all the characters from the set.For e.g, substrings that contain only a's, only b's, only c's or only a,b's or only b,c's or only c,a's. I gave him the naive O(n^2) solution by generating all substrings and testing them.

The interviewer wanted an O(n) solution.

Edit: My attempt was to have the last indexes of a,b,c and run a pointer from left to right, and anytime all 3 were counted, change the start of the substring to exclude the earliest one and start counting again. It doesn't seem exhaustive

So for e.g, if the string is `abbcabccaa`,
let `i` be the pointer that traverses the string. Let `start` be start of the substring.

1) i = 0, start = 0

2) i = 1, start = 0, last_index(a) = 0 --> 1 substring - a

3) i = 2, start = 0, last_index(a) = 0, last_index(b) = 1 -- > 1 substring ab

4) i = 3, start = 0, last_index(a) = 0, last_index(b) = 2 --> 1 substring abb

5) i = 4, start = 1, last_index(b) = 2, last_index(c) = 3 --> 1 substring bbc(removed a from the substring)

6) i = 5, start = 3, last_index(c) = 3, last_index(a) = 4 --> 1 substring ca(removed b from the substring)

but this isn't exhaustive

Comment: It was a generic question, no language specified? Also, do you have any attempts at all or notions how to approach the problem?

Comment: I answered in C/C++, but I figure the logic would be language independent

Comment: I'm afraid the problem is not well defined. What happens with inputs of the form "a....aba....a" ? Clearly there are O(N^2) distinct substrings in it that contain only a and b. This makes the running time at least O(N^2).

Comment: It's a trick question: An input of 'ab' has the expected result ['a', 'b', 'ab']. So the result has more elements than the input. There can't be an O(n) solution.

Comment: By the way, if the question was to *count* the number of substrings, then this could have been done in linear time, as required.

Comment: @EyalSchneider How do we do it if its just to count?

Comment: @Aks do you need all unique substrings ?

Comment: preferably yes, but if there's a O(n) solution which repeats substrings, should be ok

Comment: @Aks: Please see my new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the problem in its original definition can't be solved in less than O(N^2) time, as some comments point out, I suggest a linear algorithm for *counting* the number of substrings (not necessarily unique in their values, but unique in their positions within the original string).

**The algorithm**

1. count = 0
2. For every char C in {'a','b','c'} scan the input S and break it into longest sequences not including C. For each such section A, add |A|*(|A|+1)/2 to count. This addition stands for the number of legal sub-strings inside A.
3. Now we have the total number of legal strings including only {'a','b'}, only {'a','c'} and only {'b','c'}. The problem is that we counted substrings with a single repeated character twice. To fix this we iterate over S again, this time *subtracting* |A|*(|A|+1)/2 for every largest sequence A of a single character that we encounter.
4. Return count

**Example**

S='aacb'

breaking it using 'a' gives us only 'cb', so count = 3. For C='b' we have 'aac', which makes count = 3 + 6 = 9. With C='c' we get 'aa' and 'b', so count = 9 + 3 + 1 = 13. Now we have to do the subtraction: 'aa': -3, 'c': -1, 'b': -1. So we have **count=8**.

The 8 substrings are:

```
'a'
'a' (the second char this time)
'aa'
'ac'
'aac'
'cb'
'c'
'b'
```

Comment: how did we arrive at `|A|*(|A|+1)/2` for number of substrings?

Comment: @Aks: Consider the |A|+1 "positions" (in between chars, before the first char and after the last) in A. Any selection of 2 different such positions gives you a different substring, so the number of substrings is c(|A|+1,2) = |A|*(|A|+1)/2. Another way to look at it is choosing any combination of two different char positions in A (|A|*(|A|-1)/2) and then adding the number of ways to select a single character (|A|).

Answer (score 0):

To get something better than O(n) we may need additional assumptions (maybe *longest substrings* with this property).
Consider a string of the form `aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbb` of length n. There is at least O(n^2) possible substrings so if we want to list them all we need O(n^2) time.

I came up with a linear solution for the *longest substrings*.

Take a set `S` of all substrings separated by `a`, all substrings separated by `b` and finally all substrings separated by `c`. Each of those steps can be done in O(n), so we have O(3n), thus O(n).

**Example:**
Take `aaabcaaccbaa`.

In this case set `S` contains:

- substrings separated by `a`: `bc`, `ccb`
- substrings separated by `b`: `aaa`, `caacc`
- substrings separated by `c`: `aaab`, `aa`, `baa`.

By the *set* I mean a data structure with adding and finding element with a given key in O(1).

Comment: That results in duplicate substrings.

Comment: By 'set' I really mean a **set**. Let's say we implement it as a hash table.

Comment: "All substrings" of 'aaa' contains 'a' three times.

Comment: Now it doesn't seem O(n).

Comment: Sure, I thought about the set at the very end as well. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: doesn't finding all substrings of the smaller strings end up in > O(n)

Comment: You are right, there probably is no O(n) solution, at least for the general case.